# How to run a sql command from the command prompt in a batch file

Tags: sql-server, batch-file

I'm looking for a simple way to run the following command from a command line. I need to run it as part of a regular old .bat file on a windows server, so I need some kind of command line utility. I looked into sqlcmd but not sure on the correct syntax and it somewhat looked complicated. I need to be able to enter a sql username and password as part of the utility to connect to the sql server, since this will be running on a different machine.

I need to run a simple command like this:

```
UPDATE ABC SET PictureName = ID + '.jpg' WHERE TYPE = 'active'
```

Ideally I would want some tool that I can simply run in this way or something similar:

```
AwesomeTool.exe -sqlUsername "username" -sqlPass "password" -sqlStatement "UPDATE ABC SET PictureName = ID + '.jpg' WHERE TYPE = 'active'"
```

By the way this needs to work in MS SQL 2008 and newer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use sqlcmd:

```
sqlcmd -U "username" -P "password" -S MySqlServer -d MyDatabase -q "UPDATE ABC SET PictureName..."
```

Comment: Are there any equivalent standalone tools that don't require any installation?